# How to set the session to MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I created the an MVC 3 application of type Empty ( not the Internet or Intranet) with user login

and

user sign up proces..

It is working fine but now let us say a user named as Ravi loged into application and browsing pages for some time and later he did not do any operations even the mouse click in the application for 3 minutes

then,

Ravi again tried to browse some pages then, the application must take him to Login page again... This is my idea.... I hope you understand my point... Now in which way we can do it....

Comment: visit http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security

Answer (score 1):

That's how [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) works out-of-the-box. You mentioned in your question that you created an Empty application and then talked about some login and signup process without explained how you have implemented it or showing some code. So the idea is that you would setup forms authentication's timeout property to 3 minutes in your web.config and then you could use the `[Authorize]` attribute to decorate controllers/actions that you need to protect and allow only authenticated users to access.

There are some nice videos from PluralSight on the [ASP.NET/MVC site](http://www.asp.net/mvc) that I invite you watching. Video 7. covers authentication and authorization in ASP.NET MVC.